# Python Curl Request works but fails in python-requests

Tags: python, python-requests

Given curl string

```
curl 'https://www.zim.com/tools/track-a-shipment?consnumber=ZIMUHKG83103991' \
  -H 'Connection: keep-alive' \
  -H 'Pragma: no-cache' \
  -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua: "Google Chrome";v="87", " Not;A Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="87"' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0' \
  -H 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1' \
  -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36' \
  -H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9' \
  -H 'Sec-Fetch-Site: none' \
  -H 'Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate' \
  -H 'Sec-Fetch-User: ?1' \
  -H 'Sec-Fetch-Dest: document' \
  -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9' \
  -H 'Cookie: AKA_A2=A; bm_sz=859787DC1D5AEE36D3600FF356A4CA8F~YAAQhH8lF45vl1t2AQAAfRHYbAqTGL8BZpk+0rK5N2995jKTFA1ciit4+ZQACw9wfRaROqpEgUUPf5TUvQgoET7V0UEvDjwY5xg0l6xAAiw4FbNZUnHVOTjTngubxeinEkrghoCxiQhq/AdqIB+FreGiWywpnHgI3z9IMHMBqQc/KlKv02bpVPYevSE=; ak_bmsc=C7C714E53E4B796E1211AC9600984FD917257F841A2700000454DA5F5A49CC00~pl/ItEDgKkZCIU+hxaat5TBhEMOXv2zyt2CNJ919cVwKQa3QF0ywZiGa+Q+uvLtwzyZDWpIoBGmgkarOL5dOIqu0/SDGI5VA/JceI79+k+9lQrXfueJ81r1hjtGdDSUdsnFDVNM7gAjW3o0g89psSGsetBksACQ2mjXnJ8DtfGczHqrxKDIDCbDqMDqN6jeCaUcFXz/ibw41v4H/oi5NPYOrusM23XvwWZN4FIojfznvQ=; rxVisitor=1608143876263VUJUR3NHRLQVUO2F35H3TCMV8J4H0S0O; uniqueUserId=73aa42f6-ec0a-454b-864c-53c929c69acc; TS01f7aa8d=01bbeceaf70e021eadf6a0b8f40c9d7dd5a5bec7a6ccf64d1d0d6c394eb5163777c70918fb97ca5438df15b736ef07fc71f2a6c2ec; country=US; stg_traffic_source_priority=1; stg_externalReferrer=; _ga=GA1.2.1554174658.1608143878; _gid=GA1.2.1910593640.1608143878; _gat=1; _fbp=fb.1.1608143877831.315235914; _pk_ses.923228e7-d119-45eb-a025-e4d1b1af6e1b.ad39=*; OptanonAlertBoxClosed=2020-12-16T18:38:01.109Z; dtCookie=v_4_srv_1_sn_TDL3JIKKQV0VSQUEIUHTBJ56TOT1CCUC_perc_100000_ol_0_mul_1_app-3A25bc709b3f2362bb_1; TS0128f558=01bbeceaf79e60a355ba941809221f59e2bdab22a4ccf64d1d0d6c394eb5163777c70918fbb71a0ba6e838fc19395ede2ae95488a7fd98954c33016e2ba9bae818d3a335ce; _abck=44FD5BBD0CC4FC22EF9781503D86E3D0~0~YAAQhH8lF5hwl1t2AQAAkFnYbAV8rcMAuxJoVV2k4I4tGS2UpDKMfmgaY6sBvo8cecA+5eMq5RGtSauAaMLSra/pqLblV2QP/N+2o59WzVzkWWiCALABMcrT/P0cn6AZkAPUTGDxXnianz/jaP/wfpzj/rhrcRBNOnBC8biMU/9WuyP1hJNcsb9WTmWO7+ZXSCVfILpA0bZXBZMwo0FW81diWk4Au1oGeLwE+/KYMiIY9pOYfj8KRee/SLWyGsD4Y5RfWUmw3O0AbxpbCfR+6yIH8te1TxfJWrmuZlYnmD29Gi3HpoTpHWvnKV6kStFZT/VFe/4rDvt+pYDleFgm1PjHJw==~-1~-1~-1; OptanonConsent=isIABGlobal=false&datestamp=Wed+Dec+16+2020+10%3A38%3A06+GMT-0800+(Pacific+Standard+Time)&version=5.14.0&landingPath=NotLandingPage&groups=1%3A1%2C2%3A1&AwaitingReconsent=false; _pk_id.923228e7-d119-45eb-a025-e4d1b1af6e1b.ad39=f088e947fbfe9b3a.1608143879.1.1608143886.1608143879.; rxvt=1608145686613|1608143876265; dtPC=1$143885937_772h-vMCAUUFGRAHJCUFRAGBMKMOHMWHSMGHRC-0e4; dtLatC=1; bm_sv=1BA15C2B6F17C2BF6D9409DFDB60C5F1~wTpbUF28mGB1T6v/l/C9Gwd75IegoN6Grly4DUy83+YSmdIruPdojsLeVejB1lAsVW2iqY3AldCDkMDwOdvjqDNBDdAbs/6npz7OoAc8Hy1i8yUx+jGzvkF88f7aAtsyQtIS+vovW58VS1jqsOnwEg==; stg_last_interaction=Wed%2C%2016%20Dec%202020%2018:38:11%20GMT; stg_returning_visitor=Wed%2C%2016%20Dec%202020%2018:38:11%20GMT; dtSa=true%7CS%7C-1%7C-%7Ct-3000%7C1608143889464%7C143885937_772%7Chttps%3A%2F%2Fwww.zim.com%2Ftools%2Ftrack-a-shipment%3Fconsnumber%3DZIMUHKG83103991%7CTrack%20Shipment%5Ec%20Container%20Tracing%20%5Ep%20ZIM%7C1608143888317%7C%7C; RT="sl=2&ss=1608143876114&tt=4112&obo=0&sh=1608143886632%3D2%3A0%3A4112%2C1608143878857%3D1%3A0%3A2741&dm=zim.com&si=ljj0gvj7mqn&rl=1&ld=1608143886632&r=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.zim.com%2Ftools%2Ftrack-a-shipment%3F201a15c26295707f7d9507ad6c103a3f&ul=1608143892112"' \
  --compressed
```

It works like magic, I get the correct response I desire from the URL.

Replicating the same EXACT thing in python-requests, I immidiately get "Access Denied"

How is curl any different from python-requests?

Here is my python-snippet code:

```
headers = {
        'Connection': 'keep-alive',
        'Pragma': 'no-cache',
        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
        'sec-ch-ua': '"Google Chrome";v="87", " Not;A Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="87"',
        'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
        'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36',
        'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
        'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
        'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'navigate',
        'Sec-Fetch-User': '?1',
        'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'document',
        'Referer': 'https://www.zim.com/tools/track-a-shipment',
        'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
        'Host':'www.zim.com',
        'cookie':'AKA_A2=A; bm_sz=859787DC1D5AEE36D3600FF356A4CA8F~YAAQhH8lF45vl1t2AQAAfRHYbAqTGL8BZpk+0rK5N2995jKTFA1ciit4+ZQACw9wfRaROqpEgUUPf5TUvQgoET7V0UEvDjwY5xg0l6xAAiw4FbNZUnHVOTjTngubxeinEkrghoCxiQhq/AdqIB+FreGiWywpnHgI3z9IMHMBqQc/KlKv02bpVPYevSE=; ak_bmsc=C7C714E53E4B796E1211AC9600984FD917257F841A2700000454DA5F5A49CC00~pl/ItEDgKkZCIU+hxaat5TBhEMOXv2zyt2CNJ919cVwKQa3QF0ywZiGa+Q+uvLtwzyZDWpIoBGmgkarOL5dOIqu0/SDGI5VA/JceI79+k+9lQrXfueJ81r1hjtGdDSUdsnFDVNM7gAjW3o0g89psSGsetBksACQ2mjXnJ8DtfGczHqrxKDIDCbDqMDqN6jeCaUcFXz/ibw41v4H/oi5NPYOrusM23XvwWZN4FIojfznvQ=; rxVisitor=1608143876263VUJUR3NHRLQVUO2F35H3TCMV8J4H0S0O; uniqueUserId=73aa42f6-ec0a-454b-864c-53c929c69acc; TS01f7aa8d=01bbeceaf70e021eadf6a0b8f40c9d7dd5a5bec7a6ccf64d1d0d6c394eb5163777c70918fb97ca5438df15b736ef07fc71f2a6c2ec; country=US; stg_traffic_source_priority=1; stg_externalReferrer=; _ga=GA1.2.1554174658.1608143878; _gid=GA1.2.1910593640.1608143878; _gat=1; _fbp=fb.1.1608143877831.315235914; _pk_ses.923228e7-d119-45eb-a025-e4d1b1af6e1b.ad39=*; OptanonAlertBoxClosed=2020-12-16T18:38:01.109Z; dtCookie=v_4_srv_1_sn_TDL3JIKKQV0VSQUEIUHTBJ56TOT1CCUC_perc_100000_ol_0_mul_1_app-3A25bc709b3f2362bb_1; TS0128f558=01bbeceaf79e60a355ba941809221f59e2bdab22a4ccf64d1d0d6c394eb5163777c70918fbb71a0ba6e838fc19395ede2ae95488a7fd98954c33016e2ba9bae818d3a335ce; _abck=44FD5BBD0CC4FC22EF9781503D86E3D0~0~YAAQhH8lF5hwl1t2AQAAkFnYbAV8rcMAuxJoVV2k4I4tGS2UpDKMfmgaY6sBvo8cecA+5eMq5RGtSauAaMLSra/pqLblV2QP/N+2o59WzVzkWWiCALABMcrT/P0cn6AZkAPUTGDxXnianz/jaP/wfpzj/rhrcRBNOnBC8biMU/9WuyP1hJNcsb9WTmWO7+ZXSCVfILpA0bZXBZMwo0FW81diWk4Au1oGeLwE+/KYMiIY9pOYfj8KRee/SLWyGsD4Y5RfWUmw3O0AbxpbCfR+6yIH8te1TxfJWrmuZlYnmD29Gi3HpoTpHWvnKV6kStFZT/VFe/4rDvt+pYDleFgm1PjHJw==~-1~-1~-1; OptanonConsent=isIABGlobal=false&datestamp=Wed+Dec+16+2020+10%3A38%3A06+GMT-0800+(Pacific+Standard+Time)&version=5.14.0&landingPath=NotLandingPage&groups=1%3A1%2C2%3A1&AwaitingReconsent=false; _pk_id.923228e7-d119-45eb-a025-e4d1b1af6e1b.ad39=f088e947fbfe9b3a.1608143879.1.1608143886.1608143879.; rxvt=1608145686613|1608143876265; dtPC=1$143885937_772h-vMCAUUFGRAHJCUFRAGBMKMOHMWHSMGHRC-0e4; dtLatC=1; bm_sv=1BA15C2B6F17C2BF6D9409DFDB60C5F1~wTpbUF28mGB1T6v/l/C9Gwd75IegoN6Grly4DUy83+YSmdIruPdojsLeVejB1lAsVW2iqY3AldCDkMDwOdvjqDNBDdAbs/6npz7OoAc8Hy1i8yUx+jGzvkF88f7aAtsyQtIS+vovW58VS1jqsOnwEg==; stg_last_interaction=Wed%2C%2016%20Dec%202020%2018:38:11%20GMT; stg_returning_visitor=Wed%2C%2016%20Dec%202020%2018:38:11%20GMT; dtSa=true%7CS%7C-1%7C-%7Ct-3000%7C1608143889464%7C143885937_772%7Chttps%3A%2F%2Fwww.zim.com%2Ftools%2Ftrack-a-shipment%3Fconsnumber%3DZIMUHKG83103991%7CTrack%20Shipment%5Ec%20Container%20Tracing%20%5Ep%20ZIM%7C1608143888317%7C%7C; RT="sl=2&ss=1608143876114&tt=4112&obo=0&sh=1608143886632%3D2%3A0%3A4112%2C1608143878857%3D1%3A0%3A2741&dm=zim.com&si=ljj0gvj7mqn&rl=1&ld=1608143886632&r=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.zim.com%2Ftools%2Ftrack-a-shipment%3F201a15c26295707f7d9507ad6c103a3f&ul=1608143892112"'
    }
    params = {
        'consnumber': 'ZIMUHKG83103991'
    }
    response = requests.get('https://www.zim.com/tools/track-a-shipment', headers=headers, params=params)
    return str(response.text)
```

I'm passing the coookies too, to replicate the request, it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: `print(response.url)` and check the url and validate, is it correct or wrong.
I guess `Referer` is not needed in headers & `cookie` too

Comment: I got rid of those, same issue.. It just tricks me that how is curl any differently making requests than the way I am? Also the response.url looks correct.

Comment: Did you check the `URL`

Comment: Yes, the URL seems fine too. https://www.zim.com/tools/track-a-shipment?consnumber=ZIMUHKG83103991 [If you try to visit that URl directly, you may get access denied, cookies are def needed]

Comment: Have you tried tracing both versions using a mitm proxy like Telerik Fiddler Classic? There has to be a difference and that should let you see it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `cookie_jar` to handle `cookies`. I have removed `cookies` from `headers` and handled with `requests.cookies.RequestsCookieJar`

```py
import requests
import http.cookies

headers = {
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Pragma': 'no-cache',
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
    'sec-ch-ua': '"Google Chrome";v="87", " Not;A Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="87"',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'navigate',
    'Sec-Fetch-User': '?1',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'document',
    'Referer': 'https://www.zim.com/tools/track-a-shipment',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'Host':'www.zim.com'
}
params = {
    'consnumber': 'ZIMUHKG83103991'
}

# cookie
cookie = 'AKA_A2=A; bm_sz=859787DC1D5AEE36D3600FF356A4CA8F~YAAQhH8lF45vl1t2AQAAfRHYbAqTGL8BZpk+0rK5N2995jKTFA1ciit4+ZQACw9wfRaROqpEgUUPf5TUvQgoET7V0UEvDjwY5xg0l6xAAiw4FbNZUnHVOTjTngubxeinEkrghoCxiQhq/AdqIB+FreGiWywpnHgI3z9IMHMBqQc/KlKv02bpVPYevSE=; ak_bmsc=C7C714E53E4B796E1211AC9600984FD917257F841A2700000454DA5F5A49CC00~pl/ItEDgKkZCIU+hxaat5TBhEMOXv2zyt2CNJ919cVwKQa3QF0ywZiGa+Q+uvLtwzyZDWpIoBGmgkarOL5dOIqu0/SDGI5VA/JceI79+k+9lQrXfueJ81r1hjtGdDSUdsnFDVNM7gAjW3o0g89psSGsetBksACQ2mjXnJ8DtfGczHqrxKDIDCbDqMDqN6jeCaUcFXz/ibw41v4H/oi5NPYOrusM23XvwWZN4FIojfznvQ=; rxVisitor=1608143876263VUJUR3NHRLQVUO2F35H3TCMV8J4H0S0O; uniqueUserId=73aa42f6-ec0a-454b-864c-53c929c69acc; TS01f7aa8d=01bbeceaf70e021eadf6a0b8f40c9d7dd5a5bec7a6ccf64d1d0d6c394eb5163777c70918fb97ca5438df15b736ef07fc71f2a6c2ec; country=US; stg_traffic_source_priority=1; stg_externalReferrer=; _ga=GA1.2.1554174658.1608143878; _gid=GA1.2.1910593640.1608143878; _gat=1; _fbp=fb.1.1608143877831.315235914; _pk_ses.923228e7-d119-45eb-a025-e4d1b1af6e1b.ad39=*; OptanonAlertBoxClosed=2020-12-16T18:38:01.109Z; dtCookie=v_4_srv_1_sn_TDL3JIKKQV0VSQUEIUHTBJ56TOT1CCUC_perc_100000_ol_0_mul_1_app-3A25bc709b3f2362bb_1; TS0128f558=01bbeceaf79e60a355ba941809221f59e2bdab22a4ccf64d1d0d6c394eb5163777c70918fbb71a0ba6e838fc19395ede2ae95488a7fd98954c33016e2ba9bae818d3a335ce; _abck=44FD5BBD0CC4FC22EF9781503D86E3D0~0~YAAQhH8lF5hwl1t2AQAAkFnYbAV8rcMAuxJoVV2k4I4tGS2UpDKMfmgaY6sBvo8cecA+5eMq5RGtSauAaMLSra/pqLblV2QP/N+2o59WzVzkWWiCALABMcrT/P0cn6AZkAPUTGDxXnianz/jaP/wfpzj/rhrcRBNOnBC8biMU/9WuyP1hJNcsb9WTmWO7+ZXSCVfILpA0bZXBZMwo0FW81diWk4Au1oGeLwE+/KYMiIY9pOYfj8KRee/SLWyGsD4Y5RfWUmw3O0AbxpbCfR+6yIH8te1TxfJWrmuZlYnmD29Gi3HpoTpHWvnKV6kStFZT/VFe/4rDvt+pYDleFgm1PjHJw==~-1~-1~-1; OptanonConsent=isIABGlobal=false&datestamp=Wed+Dec+16+2020+10%3A38%3A06+GMT-0800+(Pacific+Standard+Time)&version=5.14.0&landingPath=NotLandingPage&groups=1%3A1%2C2%3A1&AwaitingReconsent=false; _pk_id.923228e7-d119-45eb-a025-e4d1b1af6e1b.ad39=f088e947fbfe9b3a.1608143879.1.1608143886.1608143879.; rxvt=1608145686613|1608143876265; dtPC=1$143885937_772h-vMCAUUFGRAHJCUFRAGBMKMOHMWHSMGHRC-0e4; dtLatC=1; bm_sv=1BA15C2B6F17C2BF6D9409DFDB60C5F1~wTpbUF28mGB1T6v/l/C9Gwd75IegoN6Grly4DUy83+YSmdIruPdojsLeVejB1lAsVW2iqY3AldCDkMDwOdvjqDNBDdAbs/6npz7OoAc8Hy1i8yUx+jGzvkF88f7aAtsyQtIS+vovW58VS1jqsOnwEg==; stg_last_interaction=Wed%2C%2016%20Dec%202020%2018:38:11%20GMT; stg_returning_visitor=Wed%2C%2016%20Dec%202020%2018:38:11%20GMT; dtSa=true%7CS%7C-1%7C-%7Ct-3000%7C1608143889464%7C143885937_772%7Chttps%3A%2F%2Fwww.zim.com%2Ftools%2Ftrack-a-shipment%3Fconsnumber%3DZIMUHKG83103991%7CTrack%20Shipment%5Ec%20Container%20Tracing%20%5Ep%20ZIM%7C1608143888317%7C%7C; RT="sl=2&ss=1608143876114&tt=4112&obo=0&sh=1608143886632%3D2%3A0%3A4112%2C1608143878857%3D1%3A0%3A2741&dm=zim.com&si=ljj0gvj7mqn&rl=1&ld=1608143886632&r=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.zim.com%2Ftools%2Ftrack-a-shipment%3F201a15c26295707f7d9507ad6c103a3f&ul=1608143892112"'
simple_cookie = http.cookies.SimpleCookie(cookie)
cookie_jar = requests.cookies.RequestsCookieJar()
cookie_jar.update(simple_cookie)

response = requests.get('https://www.zim.com/tools/track-a-shipment', headers=headers, params=params, cookies=cookie_jar)
return str(response.text)
```

Comment: If you look at the response, I get "Access Denied" still. If you do the same thing via CURL request, you get the actual response and not access denied.

Comment: I tried the solution, no luck. Still "Access Denied"